# Development economics papers that used Difference-in-Differences

Tags: development-economics

I need to write an assignment paper in development economics that explains the concept of differences-in-differences estimation, and I feel like it can certainly be helpful to look at some examples that actually used this method.

So I wish to look for some sample papers which dealt with issues in development economics that used
the difference-in-differences method as a reference for the paper.

I spent some time searching for examples but it's been surprisingly difficult to find actual example papers displaying this method (I was only able to find hypothetical examples or examples used in the United States). Maybe there is a problem with my searching method.

Is there a website where I can specifically find examples or sample papers on development economics (so the estimation has to be used in developing countries) that used Differences-in-Differences? I think there are friends here who are used to searching for or writing papers like this, and I would appreciate advice on places to refer to or how to find these kinds of papers that match my needs.

Comment: Well find a journal that publish article within developmental economics and search that journal on "diff-and-diff" si one approach. Doing that I found for example: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0304387818306084

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A very good paper that I had in my MA curriculum is Jaychandran and Pande, AER 2017: https://www.aeaweb.org/articles?id=10.1257/aer.20151282 (I believe this paper has open access, maybe on one of the authors' websites).

Working through this paper should help you understand DID quite thoroughly. The paper also employs double and even triple DID.

Comment: '+1' very nice paper indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Qian's paper about women's labor productivity and missing women.
Edit: [Here is a link](https://watermark.silverchair.com/123-3-1251.pdf?token=AQECAHi208BE49Ooan9kkhW_Ercy7Dm3ZL_9Cf3qfKAc485ysgAAAvkwggL1BgkqhkiG9w0BBwagggLmMIIC4gIBADCCAtsGCSqGSIb3DQEHATAeBglghkgBZQMEAS4wEQQMjBEHXMsVKGpmgsnXAgEQgIICrOBY_GhXz-ZQLb_96XeKJbRk6FYt7rR_WWvKuMPPLQmnwRVRrxfoWD8aUXZ6-GG9R2AKzeaPF6FtTRjcAeN-K_o_uuj9etcIZrK6cTOivXkg5ApOXisHXd1GBcemSW-K69TDzXQrsihmD91U71s-LBkrU2j0-lH7XbpvRWmgc4q1HgggXxaai7Uf-5dgmOWATq7fYCKvDbGKmWwg_EqOI9gABZlVBkoxHv5boc79Xpck2vtwyTZCssomA2650X2XdBB-UNhukvTgkKbaHm_yMYYdUISQuvtahao653kbyxUlZho0f6-qEzGBf61caYgq5rd4DnzXpCl3E9d9QUCbfzjqbyX_vF5SQJ6_XKqMY3VnEMdOvVZxNRBUVhTdZd2li1F86VPk_lY8kEZY5hIZ8smiFE1eHqmOrAyA54B5CwMvYfnLxkVgwh7JbDJjo0vOVYqBeHt-B3skkGm9UB0RFVzfdjsuBDnBKgr5UKGKUlSMjHtLiiRCMEnuQVgP7wk9NtdroIEZR3oGywftNpU5gRnmKon2OfhKDECBmEhjROhM0lvXOJUh2z7X9ZBy6q2awVSP__ecl-1ywsyYxDcI8a6BZahMmOiAcv-fq7Ycb_Feeqv6roMTd12QdC4aJJN-UV3jLo16nNixe5B-t2jsuwnLAAlv5r-fergZXV7CcOems8EBICUQ1vUtWBDJq-mnEVmn8fNCYONsPBcxSdgX_en1ITfzQsahhThr9m5ZyFxm_uiLki9yoIgYNtKsMqpx6OCKNH3RQfKFx5SmLw5YB9qWtO29VP80eJD0ZWZBf9WWgC908NGKq5TUeDk497yVl-hAUXBtMM1HMio2SjULO_8TjyopzgANk7SplFEhTX-7w3GmQjAOM9XFXT359uM3Ezt_aTDNPIkJph41fA).

Also, [there is another recent diff-in-diff development paper.](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S0304387821000638?token=53518410D49DFD7E615CFB98D1E35CCEBF614E41BD14DC4FB2A826BB9905EECAEED16B59C5238F05C548084B5E75F53C&originRegion=us-east-1&originCreation=20210628171418)

Comment: Hi, please consider providing either link to the paper or full reference.

Answer (score 0):

We had [Banerjee and Duflo, 2008](https://economics.mit.edu/files/2707) in a class. Nice paper.